# How to get a detailed overview of some articles

Tags: reactjs, django

import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { Card } from 'antd';

class ArticleDetail extends React.Component {

```
state = {
    article: {}
}

componentDidMount() {
    const articleID = this.props.match.params.articleID;
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${articleID}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                article: res.data
            });
            
        })
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Card title={this.state.article.title}>
            <p>{this.state.article.content}</p>
            </Card>
        </div>            
    )
}
```

}

export default ArticleDetail;

Comment: can you please provide more detailed question about what you want to do and what obstacle you are in?

Comment: does this related to Django in anyway?

Comment: What does it means 'detailed overview of some articles'?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Make sure on your article.js file under title link you use  `  instead of  '  

<List.Item.Meta
          avatar={<Avatar src={item.avatar} />}
          title={<a href={`/${item.id}`}>{item.title}</a>}   //here
          description={item.description}
        />
        {item.content}
</List.Item>`
```

//And under your routes.js file make sure the (article Id) is the same as the one you used on the Article-detail-view

```
     exact path='/:articleID' component={ArticleDetail}
```